# StartDate in daterangepicker doesn't work in the second input

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, momentjs, daterangepicker

When I try in first input to create startDate it work but I need startDate for second input, the result is not work.
Here is my code

```
$('.date-picker').daterangepicker({
  singleDatePicker: true,
  minDate: moment().subtract(1, 'years'),
  maxDate: moment().subtract(1, 'days'),
  locale: {
        format: 'DD-MM-YYYY'
      }
  }, function(chosen_date) {
      $('.date-picker').val(chosen_date.format('DD-MM-YYYY'));
    })

  $('.date-picker-2').daterangepicker({
    minDate: departpicker,
    /*why is not working?*/
    startDate: moment(departpicker, 'DD-MM-YYYY').add(6, 'days'),
    maxDate: moment(departpicker, 'DD-MM-YYYY').add(6, 'days')
})
```

Here is my full code [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dedi_wibisono17/67drajgz/5/)

I hope when I select 06-08-2018, the startDate in second input is 12-08-2018. like this picture
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to change the start date of the second date-time picker.Currently it sets to the initial date, Hope this helps.

```
var drp = $('.date-picker-2').data('daterangepicker');
drp.setStartDate(moment(departpicker, 'DD-MM-YYYY').add(6, 'days'));
```

Comment: Hi @Sachi if I change minDate, it will be just one day. the range of 6 days is gone, is there an idea?

Comment: Hi @Sachi still doesn't work. would you like show the demo?. I have try code that you create. https://jsfiddle.net/dedi_wibisono17/67drajgz/39/ . correct me if i wrong. Thanks

Comment: you have added
drp.setStartDate(moment(departpicker, 'DD-MM-YYYY').add(6, 'days'));
drp.setStartDate(departpicker);
remove the secound line
keep only
drp.setStartDate(moment(departpicker, 'DD-MM-YYYY').add(6, 'days'));

Comment: oh i see, it work, my fault. Thank you for your explain it.

Answer (score 0):

As a `minDate` for `.date-picker-2`, you only provided the string outputted from the first datepicker... Instead of a date object.

Here is the change I made:

```
minDate: moment(departpicker, 'DD-MM-YYYY'),  //departpicker,
/*why is not working?*/
```

I also commented this additional attempt to set dates:

```
//var drp = $('.date-picker-2').data('daterangepicker');
//drp.setStartDate(departpicker);
//drp.setEndDate(departpicker);
```

It's working fine below:

```js
var autoupdate = false;

function date1(){
  $('.date-picker').daterangepicker({
    singleDatePicker: true,
    showDropdowns: true,
    minDate: moment().subtract(1, 'years'),
    autoApply: true,
    disabledDays: 'today',
    maxDate: moment().subtract(1, 'days'),
    autoUpdateInput: autoupdate,
    locale: {
      format: 'DD-MM-YYYY'
    }
  }, function(chosen_date) {
    $('.date-picker').val(chosen_date.format('DD-MM-YYYY'));
  });
}
date1();

$('.date-picker').on('apply.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {

  if ($('.date-picker').val().length == 0 ){
    autoupdate = true;
    console.log('true');
    date1();
  }
  var departpicker = $('.date-picker').val();
  
  $('.date-picker-2').daterangepicker({
    minDate: moment(departpicker, 'DD-MM-YYYY'), //departpicker,
    /*why is not working?*/
    startDate: moment(departpicker, 'DD-MM-YYYY').add(6, 'days'),
    maxDate: moment(departpicker, 'DD-MM-YYYY').add(6, 'days'),
    singleDatePicker: true,
    showDropdowns: true,
    autoApply: true,
    locale: {
      format: 'DD-MM-YYYY'
    }
  });

  //var drp = $('.date-picker-2').data('daterangepicker');
  //drp.setStartDate(departpicker);
  //drp.setEndDate(departpicker);
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" class="date-picker">
<input type="text" class="date-picker-2">
```